# SharePoint Graph API - Update metadata on a child records

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am trying to update metadata field on a child record. I know how to update metadata field at the item level which is the folder where the file records are stored.

Currently I can list the files in a folder with the following URL string.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/sitesID/drives/drivesID/items/itemsID/children

Is there a way  to list a children/child by ID so that I list a specific record?